# Rails: Do we create concern for code reuse only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to rails so please bear with me. I went through a bunch of articles online and they say I can use concern for code reuse purpose.

I am working on something where I am creating a hash which will only be used by my service.

So wondering code reuse means if the code in concern will be used by other methods or services etc? If no then do I need to create concern for hash?

Comment: I think you should post an example.

Comment: code reuse means instead of writing the same code twice, write it once and reuse it in more than one place in your app/website. So no, you don't need to use concerns etc. if your code is small and used only in one place anyway.

Comment: You don't need to create a concern for a hash used in one place. If this hash is dynamic - create a method for it, otherwise put it into a constant.

Comment: similar to a module, although a concern could be used for code reuse, even if it's only used in one place it can be useful for splitting up a large model into multiple files.